# Conditionally Explode Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can we conditionally explode multiple array columns in Spark SQL?

My input looks like this:

```
col_1  col2             col3
123    ["id_1","id_2"]  ["tim","steve"]
456    ["id_3","id_4"]  ["jenny"]
```

I need to transform this such that:

1. The array items with the same index are mapped to the same line
2. If there is only 1 entry in `col3`, it applies to every row

output should look like:

```
col_1   col2    col3
123     id_1    tim
123     id_2    steve
456     id_3    jenny
456     id_4    jenny
```

I have tried various combinations of explodes and lateral views, but each has returned a combination of rows that don't match the desired, or an error message.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (123, ["id_1", "id_2"], ["tim", "steve"]),
        (456, ["id_3", "id_4"], ["jenny"]),
    ],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

spark.sql("""
select 
  col1,
  col1_d,
  col2_d
from my_table
    lateral view explode(col2) exploded_col as col1_d
    lateral view explode(col3) exploded_col_2 as col2_d
""").show()

+----+------+------+
|col1|col1_d|col2_d|
+----+------+------+
| 123|  id_1|   tim|
| 123|  id_1| steve|
| 123|  id_2|   tim|
| 123|  id_2| steve|
| 456|  id_3| jenny|
| 456|  id_4| jenny|
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: How do you deal with the case where you've 3 entries in col2 and 2 in col3? For ex. `(123, ["id_1", "id_2", "id_3"], ["tim", "steve"]),`?

Comment: This should never be the case.  However, col2 may sometimes be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data is properly validated for condition that:

- If "col3" > 1, then len("col2") == len("col3")
- Or "col3" == 1

You can achieve this by `array_repeat` function to repeat "col3" for len("col2"). For corner case where "col2" is null, simply convert it to an empty array:

```py
df = df.withColumn("col3", 
                   F.when((F.size("col2") > 0)&(F.size("col3") == 1), F.array_repeat(F.element_at("col3", 1), F.size("col2"))) \
                   .otherwise(F.col("col3")) \
                   )

df = df.withColumn("col2", 
                   F.when((F.col("col2").isNull())|(F.size("col2") == 0), F.array(F.lit(""))) \
                   .otherwise(F.col("col2")) \
                   )

+----+------------+--------------+
|col1|        col2|          col3|
+----+------------+--------------+
| 123|[id_1, id_2]|  [tim, steve]|
| 456|[id_3, id_4]|[jenny, jenny]|
| 789|          []|       [harry]|
+----+------------+--------------+
```

Then zip "col2" and "col3" together using `arrays_zip` and finally `explode`:

```py
df = df \
  .withColumn("col2_col3", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("col2", "col3"))) \
  .select("col1", F.col("col2_col3.col2").alias("col2"), F.col("col2_col3.col3").alias("col3"))

+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
| 123|id_1|  tim|
| 123|id_2|steve|
| 456|id_3|jenny|
| 456|id_4|jenny|
| 789|    |harry|
+----+----+-----+
```

Dataset used:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (123, ["id_1", "id_2"], ["tim", "steve"]),
        (456, ["id_3", "id_4"], ["jenny"]),
        (789, None, ["harry"]),
    ],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
)

+----+------------+------------+
|col1|        col2|        col3|
+----+------------+------------+
| 123|[id_1, id_2]|[tim, steve]|
| 456|[id_3, id_4]|     [jenny]|
| 789|        null|     [harry]|
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: This works, can you show me how I'd handle the edge case where col2 is null but col3 is populated? ex. `(789, null, ["joey", "stacey"])`.   Apologies I just noticed this edge case :)